# I can't find out why my form doesn't send info to Mailchimp API

Tags: javascript, forms, api, mailchimp

I'm breaking my head right now. And can't find out why my code isn't working.
I need to connect a form to Mailchimp.
I put the right API key/list ID.
Did I miss something? #help

My JS knowledge is average. I created this code from some templates I found.

Thanks a lot :D

```js
<?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

  // Mailchimp

if(!empty($_POST['newsletter']) && isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fname = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us15';
        $listID = 'b8c5013790';

        // MailChimp API URL
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'pending',
            'merge_fields'  => [
                'FNAME'     => $fname,
                'PHONE'     => $phone
            ]
        ]);

        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        // store the status message based on response code
        if ($httpCode == 200) {
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #34A853">You have successfully subscribed to CodexWorld.</p>';
        } else {
            switch ($httpCode) {
                case 214:
                    $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                    break;
                default:
                    $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                    break;
            }
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
    }
}
// end mailchimp

if  ( isset ($_POST['name']) and isset ($_POST['email']) and isset ($_POST['message']) ){
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $rappel = $_POST['period'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $ville = $_POST['city'];
  $net = $_POST['net'];
  $tv = $_POST['tv'];
  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
  $file_attach  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $file_attach_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.com";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->setFrom('xxx@xxx.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('$email', '$name');
$cnt=count($_FILES['file']['name']);
   if($cnt > 0){
     for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
       $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['file']['name'][$i],'base64',$_FILES['file']['type'][$i]);
     }
   }

    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Message de votre site ' . $client . ' - ' . $name;
        //Keep it simple - don't use HTML
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        //Build a simple message body
        $mail->Body = file_get_contents('rd-mailform.tpl');

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartName} -->", "<!-- #{Name} -->"],
            ["Nom:", $_POST['name']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartPhone} -->", "<!-- #{Phone} -->"],
            ["T&#233;l&#233;phone:", $_POST['phone']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartEmail} -->", "<!-- #{Email} -->"],
            ["Email:", $_POST['email']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartRappel} -->", "<!-- #{Rappel} -->"],
            ["P&#233;riode de rappel:", $_POST['period']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{MessageStart} -->", "<!-- #{Message} -->"],
            ["Message:", $_POST['message']],
            $mail->Body);

       $mail->Body = $mail->Body."Adresse IP de l'expéditeur: $ssIPAddress / Localisation <a href='http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=$ssIPAddress'>ici</a>, <a href='http://www.ip-tracker.org/ip-to-location.php?ip=$ssIPAddress'>ici</a> et <a href='http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ssIPAddress'>ici</a></p>";

        //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {

    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
     print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=success.php\">";
 }
}
?>
```

I thought there were a problem with my API key or the API center (i saw on documentation that I may have to add us15 in front of url. Should I?

Merge fields are good. Link between the form and Mailchimp worked before, so I don't know what happened.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's because I had to change "pending" status to "subscribed".